# Unexpected namespace prefix xmnls found for tag RelativeLayout

Tags: android

```
    ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/ScrollView01"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

 <RelativeLayout 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"   //here's the error    
    tools:context=".MainActivity4" >



<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
      android:id="@+id/view_pager"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="match_parent" />


<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/RelativeLayout01"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/LinearLayout01"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" >


        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/TextView01"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_margin="20dip"
            android:text="Divisoria"
            android:textSize="30px" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView1"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:src="@drawable/divisoria" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/TextView02"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_margin="20dip"
            android:text="Divisoria is a bargain hunter’s haven. Filipinos visit Divisoria all year round to scour each nook for great bargain finds and to buy needed business supplies in bulk. The crowd gets heavier come Christmastime, especially when most of the streets in the place are converted into Night Market areas. For those who seek a cooler shopping place, malls such as 168 Mall, Meisic Mall, and Divisoria Mall are available." 
            android:textSize="30px" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/TextView03"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_margin="20dip"
            android:text="Location: Recto Ave, Tondo, Manila, Metro Manila" 
            android:textSize="30px" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/TextView04"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_margin="20dip"
            android:text="Quiapo Church" 
            android:textSize="30px" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView2"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/quiapo" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/TextView05"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_margin="20dip"
            android:text="Pinoy private drivers are often advised not to use Quiapo’s main thoroughfares on a Friday. Devotees of the Black Nazarene fill the area around Quiapo Church to hear mass and seek the services of fortune tellers and herbal medicine peddlers. Aside from this, the whole stretch of R. Hidalgo Street is packed with shoppers buying from its many street vendors and legitimate establishments." 
            android:textSize="30px" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/TextView06"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_margin="20dip"
            android:text="Quiapo Location: Quiapo Church, Quezon Boulevard, Manila, Metro Manila- Quipo" 
            android:textSize="30px" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/TextView07"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_margin="20dip"
            android:text="Ongpin Street" 
            android:textSize="30px" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView3"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/ongpin" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/TextView08"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_margin="20dip"
            android:text="Ongpin Street is where Pinoys and Tsinoys troop to find anything Chinese, as it is found in Chinatown itself. The ten-block-long street is rich in jewelry shops selling high-carat gold, as well as Chinese fast food joints, hardware shops, and Chinese herbal drugstores. Its close proximity to Divisoria and Quiapo makes it a favorite shopping destination come Christmas gift-buying season." 
            android:textSize="30px" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/TextView09"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_margin="20dip"
            android:text="Ongpin Location: Ongpin St, Manila, Metro Manila" 
            android:textSize="30px" />

         <TextView
            android:id="@+id/TextView10"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_margin="20dip"
            android:text="Intramuros" 
            android:textSize="30px" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView4"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/intramuros" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/TextView1"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_margin="20dip"
            android:text="Intramuros, the Walled City, is the oldest district of Manila and is rich in culture and tradition. Spanish-era churches, convents, schools, and other old buildings speak of historical value. Presently, the district is maintained by the Intramuros Administration Office. The agency oversees the maintenance and operation of the place and its many museums." 
            android:textSize="30px" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/TextView12"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_margin="20dip"
            android:text="Intramuros Location: Intramuros, Manila, Metro Manila" 
            android:textSize="30px" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/TextView13"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_margin="20dip"
            android:text="Rizal Park" 
            android:textSize="30px" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView5"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/rizalpark" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/TextView14"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_margin="20dip"
            android:text="Rizal Park, also called the Luneta, is located next to Intramuros. It was built as a tribute to the national hero, Dr. Jose Rizal, who was shot in the same place in 1896. The park is divided into the Agrifina Circle along Taft Avenue, the 22-hectare park covering the block in between Taft Avenue and Roxas Boulevard, and the Quirino Grandstand fronting Manila Bay. On normal days, visitors crowd the place to relax or visit the smaller areas such as the Orchidarium and Butterfly Pavilion. During special events, Quirino Grandstand transforms into a theater with a sea of people facing it." 
            android:textSize="30px" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/TextView15"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_margin="20dip"
            android:text="Rizal Park Location: Rizal Park, Roxas Blvd Ermita, Barangay 666 Zone 72, Manila, 1000 Metro Manila, Philippines" 
            android:textSize="30px" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/TextView16"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_margin="20dip"
            android:text="Manila Baywalk" 
            android:textSize="30px" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView6"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/baywalk" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/TextView17"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_margin="20dip"
            android:text="The Manila Baywalk is the long stretch of beautifully paved and lighted sidewalks covering the area between the US Embassy and the Cultural Center of the Philippines. In the morning, the area is often full of joggers, walkers, and bicycle riders going through their exercise routines. As the sun sets, people stop and sit by the benches or on the sea wall to appreciate the sight." 
            android:textSize="30px" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/TextView18"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_margin="20dip"
            android:text="Manila Baywalk Location: Manila Baywalk, Roxas Blvd, Malate, Manila, Metro Manila" 
            android:textSize="30px" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/TextView19"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_margin="20dip"
            android:text="Malate" 
            android:textSize="30px" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView7"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/malate" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/TextView20"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_margin="20dip"
            android:text="Malate is another spot in Manila that is rich in history. During the American Period, Malate was developed as a prime residential spot for American families, which accounts for the proliferation of buildings displaying American architecture. Present-day Malate is known for its colorful nightlife. Night clubs and bars are situated along M. H. del Pilar, Mabini, M. Adriatico, and Remedios to cater to those in search of a fun night out." 
            android:textSize="30px" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/TextView21"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_margin="20dip"
            android:text="Malate Location: Malate, Manila, 1004 Metro Manila"
            android:textSize="30px" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/TextView22"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_margin="20dip"
            android:text="Manila Zoo" 
            android:textSize="30px" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView8"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/manilazoo" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/TextView23"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_margin="20dip"
            android:text="On 25 July 1959, the Manila Zoo was opened to the public to serve as a venue for educational trips geared towards discovering the Philippines’ various flora and fauna. The zoo covers 5.5 hectares of land and has a population of over 500 animals. Aside from viewing the animals in the zoo, visitors also get to enjoy the place’s souvenir shop and playground, and may rent a boatin order to go on the lagoon." 
            android:textSize="30px" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/TextView24"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_margin="20dip"
            android:text="Manila Zoo Location: Manila Zoological and Botanical Garden, Adriatico Street, Malate, Manila, Metro Manila" 
            android:textSize="30px" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/TextView25"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_margin="20dip"
            android:text="Manila Ocean Park" 
            android:textSize="30px" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView9"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/oceanpark" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/TextView26"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_margin="20dip"
            android:text="The Manila Ocean Park is an oceanarium in Manila, Philippines. It is owned by China Oceanis Philippines Inc., a subsidiary of China Oceanis Inc., a Singaporean-registered firm that has operated four oceanariums in China. It is located behind the Quirino Grandstand at Rizal Park. It opened on March 1, 2008. In terms of floor space, the 8,000 square metres (86,000 sq ft) oceanarium is larger than the Sentosa Underwater World oceanarium in Singapore, and features a 25-metre (82 ft) underwater acrylic tunnel." 
        android:textSize="30px" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/TextView27"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_margin="20dip"
            android:text="Manila Ocean Park Location: Manila Ocean Park, 666, Behind Quirino Grandstand, Luneta, Manila, Metro Manila 1000" 
            android:textSize="30px" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/TextView28"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_margin="20dip"
            android:text="Avenida Rizal" 
            android:textSize="30px" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView10"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/avenidarizal" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/TextView29"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_margin="20dip"
            android:text="Rizal Avenue also known as 'Avenida' or 'Avenida Rizal; is one of Manila's main thoroughfares. Named after the national hero José Rizal, it is a part of Radial Road 9 (R-9). The LRTA's LRT Line 1 elevated railroad is built above the street in its entire length, and several jeepneys ply the area taking passengers from Caloocan and Quezon City. Most of the street is within the Sta. Cruz district." 
            android:textSize="30px" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/TextView30"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_margin="20dip"
            android:text="Avenida Rizal Location: Genesis Avenida, Doroteo Jose Street, Santa Cruz, Manila, Metro Manila" 
            android:textSize="30px" />
             </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Comment: Try placing `xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"` in your root layout

Comment: its says the markup in the document following the root element must well be formed

Comment: Your need a `<` before your ScrollView

Comment: its ok now, thanks :)

Comment: I posted it as an answer, accept it if it works. Thanks

Comment: btw, im having a hard time with my codes. Im trying to do a image that can be swipe and also can scroll down. But whenever i run it, the text and other images doesn't display. If you want i can send you my codes through your gmail? :)

Comment: Post a new question please

Comment: but it is hard if i posted it here, its better if i send you the codes so you can see the problem

Comment: It doesn't work like that, here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `ScrollView/>` tag is not well formed.
You should add a `<`.

Comment: where can i see that?

Comment: Click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from hollow to green. Also check this http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work